# Same numbering in Theorem and Proof

Tags: thesis

In my thesis, if number theorem statement is `1.12`, proof is coming as `1.13`. How to make the number of proof as
`1.12`?

I use

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[secn]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[secn]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[secn]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{problem}[secn]{Problem}
\newtheorem{pd}{Problem Statement}
\newtheorem{proof}[secn]{Proof}
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}
```

I am getting like this:

Lemma 2.9
........................................

......................................

Proof 2.10 We have two cases.

This is not working:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[secn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[secn]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[secn]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[secn]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{problem}[secn]{Problem}
\newtheorem{pd}{Problem Statement}
\newtheorem{proof}[secn]{Proof}


\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
%newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
% ...
%\newtheorem{proof}[theorem]{Proof} % 'proof' and 'theorem' use same counter variable

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}}
```

Comment: If you're using [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), you don't need to define a `proof` environment using `\newtheorem`; it already exists. Are you getting any errors with your current setup?

Comment: traditionally, proofs are not numbered.  if you are using `amsthm`, you can give a theorem a `\label` (say `\label{thm:xxx}`) and for the proof (not the one you have redefined, but the original), enter it as `\begin{[proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:xxx}`.

Comment: Proof comes as 1.13 and you want it to come as 1.13?

Comment: Please, make a minimal example of what you're doing; no need to have 12 theorems, one suffices.

Comment: I can not use amsthm as it conflicts my class file.

Comment: Can you use the `ntheorem` package in lieu of `amsthm`?

Comment: Yes, I can use this package.

Answer (score 3):

This assigns every proof the number of the immediately preceding statement, but with an optional argument to override it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{pd}{Problem Statement}

\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{proofinner}{Proof}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][]
 {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    % no optional argument
    \renewcommand\theproofinner{\thetheorem}%
  \else
    \renewcommand{\theproofinner}{#1}%
  \fi
  \proofinner}
 {\endproofinner}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:main}
Main theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
Whatever
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Here it is.
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Whatever
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Here it is.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[\ref{thm:main}]
Proof of main.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One could manually subtract `1` from the theorem counter after the end of Theorem 1.12 and before the start of the associated proof. This procedure may be automated with the help of the `etoolbox` package and its `\AtBeginEnvironment` directive.

(This assumes that the `proof` environment should *always* carry the same number as its associated theorem-like environment. If you need to override this on occasion, simply provide an `\addtocounter{theorem}{1}` statement before `\begin{proof}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
% ...
\newtheorem{proof}[theorem]{Proof} % 'proof' and 'theorem' use same counter variable

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{theorem}{11}

\begin{theorem} bla bla bla \end{theorem}
\begin{proof}   ble ble ble \end{proof}

\end{document}
```